# Weight random number towards range

Tags: python, random, probability

Let's say I'm getting  random number in the range using:

```
random.randrange(100)
```

Let's say that if it gives a number less than or equal to 25, you win and if it gives a number greater than 25, I win. I would then have a 75% chance to win.

How can I weight the chances of the number being greater than 25 by some percentage, say 1%.

So basically I'm trying to tilt the odds of me winning by another 1%, without changing just saying, "you win at 24 or less."

Let me know if this is unclear.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Wouldn't you just change the number to 24, then? So you have a 76% chance of winning.

Comment: @jape any version. But I'm using 3.5

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yeah that'd be the go-to idea...but for this gambling scenario we want the player to win in the range of 0-25, which is important for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want "unfair" dice, so to speak.

One way to get this, if you know the desired odds of winning, is to first decide whether you win or not. If you win, then choose a number among the winning numbers. If you lose, choose a number among the losing numbers.

For example:

```
import random

def die_roll():
    if random.random() < 0.26:
        return random.randrange(25)  # 0 to 24
    return random.randrange(25, 100)  # 25 to 99
```

Comment: Even better answer, thanks! I knew it would be obvious, but my mind was bending trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want 1% of 25% you need to use a larger sample and use a value accordingly: 100000 and 249750.

Another solution is adding an if with a change of 1% winning if the player lost the first try.

```
if random.range(100) > 25
  return "You Win"
else
 if random.range(100) < 1
   return "You Win"
 else
  return "You Lose"
```

Comment: But we want you to win at 0-25. Changing the number to 26 breaks the rules and doesn't help my cause.

Answer (score 1):

Get a random number smaller than your range. Say you want 1-100 with mostly 60s.

Random 1-5

When 1, random 60-69

Otherwise, random 1-100

Will be 28% 60s, if my math is correct

--z

For your example, I believe you'd want to random 1-100, then on 1 random 26-100. That's not exactly a 1% increase, but you can fiddle with the math to get the percents you want.

Comment: I think this'll work. I'd do random 0-100 and when 1(or any single number) random 26-100 otherwise random 0-100. That works to give me 1% advantage right?

Comment: @user3055938 let me think on the math and post an update, but yes, it would be very, very close to 1% advantage.